# How can i instantiate a class which needs access to it's 'instantiators' methods?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a class, a() with method a1(). In a1() i instantiate class b(), how can i make it so that b() can access all public vars, methods from a()? Without extending it. Class b() is a class i use in several locations, but i would like b() to be able to access the class wherein it's instantiated. Alternative is to instantiate and pass all vars and stuff into it but that seems rather ugly and not flexible enough anyway.

```
class a{
 var $test = 'yes'; // I want b() to be able to reach all public stuff in a()
 private $b;

 public function a1(){
  $this->b = new b();
  $this->b->b1();
 }
}

class b{
 public function b1(){
  echo $this->test; // Should echo 'yes'
 }
}

$temp = new a();
$temp->a1(); // Should echo 'yes'
```

Comment: Let b extend from a and it will have access to it

Comment: Rizier123: no good unfortunately :-) i do not want b to extend. The class is fully functional on it's own and i do not want to bind both.

Comment: do you really need a new b each time the function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comment blow, the only other way to extrapolate the data from one class to another without extending is using reflection.

I can go into full detail, but an example says a 1000 words.
http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

Reflection can get really powerful if used properly. However, I'd say this is one of the cases where it does not and I would suggest restructuring you classes, maybe a good way to do that is with traits. Simply put; copy pasting methods into classes.

You could also pass the class as argument, but its usage slightly changes then.

```
    class a{
        public $test = 'yes'; // I want b() to be able to reach all public stuff in a()
        public $b;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->b = new b($this);
        }
    }

    class b{
        private $instance;

        public function b1(){
            echo $this->instance->test; // Should echo 'yes'
        }

        public function __construct($instance){
            if($instance instanceof a){
                $this->instance = $instance;
            } else {
                echo "argument is not a member of 'a'";
            }
        }
    }

    $temp = new a();
    $temp->b->b1(); // Should echo 'yes'
?>
```

Comment: Xorifelse: as above, i do not want to bind both classes. so extending is not an option. class b is used in lot more other classes.

Comment: I see you've updated your question, so I've updated mine.

Comment: Last update, tested and fixed the code. You can also mark $b as private in class "a" and add public methods to "a" to access data from $b.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class a{
    var $test = 'yes'; // I want b() to be able to reach all public stuff in a()
    protected $b;

    public function a1(){
        $this->b = new b($this);
        $this->b->b1();
    }
}

class b{
    private $_parent = null;

    public function __construct($parent) {
        $this->_parent = $parent;
    }

    public function b1() {
        echo $this->_parent->test; // Should echo 'yes'
    }
}

$temp = new a();
$temp->a1(); // Should echo 'yes'
```

Comment: You just need to make sure that b has knowledge of a

Comment: why did you make two answers?

Comment: isn't this a way to extend without being explicit about it?

Comment: I made a post while the OP was editing his to say he didn't want to extend. I have now deleted it. To your 2nd question, yes it is a way to extend without extending. You pass a reference of the parent to the child. This is not a best practice, but without it the only choice is to extend